# In MySQL how to use expression to generate columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Now I want to create a table which contains the students' scores. There are four columns: `student_id`,`homework_score`,`exam_score` and `final_score`. I want to make the final_score is generated by an expression: Round(homework_score * 0.3 + final_score * 0.7). And following is my SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE course (
student_id CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
homework_score INT NULL,
exam_score INT NULL,
final_score INT NULL DEFAULT Round((homework_score * 0.3 + exam_score * 0.7),0),
PRIMARY KEY (student_id))ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When I tried to execute the SQL, MySQL said there was a syntax error in `DEFAULT Round((homework_score * 0.3 + exam_score * 0.7),0)`.
I am new with MySQL and I can't figure out what's wrong with my SQL. If anyone can help me, I will be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `default` constraint must be a constant.  Starting in MySQL 5.7.?, MySQL supported generated columns.  You can express this as:

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    student_id CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    homework_score INT NULL,
    exam_score INT NULL,
    final_score INT as ( Round((homework_score * 0.3 + exam_score * 0.7), 0) ),
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

In earlier versions, you would need to use a view, or perhaps triggers, to generate the value.